# MYSQL/PHP Echo Average of foreign key parameters

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to figure out how to have 2 SQL statements back to back, which creates a table with the info from the first SQL statement, and the last cell be the average of one of the columns from said table.

I can display the info needed to make the table. No problem. It's this:

```
$sql = "SELECT golfer_name, golfer_handicap, golfer_ghin FROM golfers WHERE trip_name_table_ID = '$userid'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($rowitem = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td style='text-align: left'>" . $rowitem['golfer_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $rowitem['golfer_handicap'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $rowitem['golfer_ghin'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
```

I can get the first colum to total the number of golfers, no problem:

```
echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Total Golfers: $result->num_rows </td>";
```

Now the trouble is trying to get the average of the handicaps in the last cell of that column. I created a 2nd SQL directly below the 1st one, but changed the variables so that they wouldn't mess with the original table data -- and inside my PHPmyAdmin SQL section, this statement returns **exactly** what I'm looking for:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT CAST(AVG(golfer_handicap) AS DECIMAL (3,1)) FROM golfers WHERE trip_name_table_ID = '$userid'";
```

But for the absolute life of me, I cannot figure out how to `echo` that single piece of data.

Answer (score -1):

You would just do it like you did the first query; keeping your variables different as to not interfere with your loop.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT golfer_name, golfer_handicap, golfer_ghin FROM golfers WHERE trip_name_table_ID = '$userid'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

$sql2 = "SELECT CAST(AVG(golfer_handicap) AS DECIMAL (3,1)) AS handicap FROM golfers WHERE trip_name_table_ID = '$userid'";
$result2 = $mysqli->query($sql2);
$total = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($rowitem = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td style='text-align: left'>" . $rowitem['golfer_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $rowitem['golfer_handicap'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $rowitem['golfer_ghin'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
```

Then just call/echo `$total["handicap"]` wherever you want to display the average.

**I have not tested the code.

Comment: instead of "$total" I used "$average" and entered this code where I wanted it to be called: `echo "<td> Average Handicap: " .$average['golfer_handicap'] . "</td>";` and it made my table disappear, and did not call the value needed.

Comment: I have updated the code a little.  I did make a mistake that would prevent the average from being calculated.  On `$result2 = mysqli->query($sql2);` I mistyped a  few things but it should be corrected now.

Comment: Okay, now this at least brought the table back, and the "Average Handicap: " text is being shown, but the average data is still not being displayed. `echo` code is same as above comment.

Comment: In the $sql2 query I have made the query return the average as ‘handicap’ key in the array.  Try `$average[‘handicap’]` or change `AS handicap` to `AS golfer_handicap`

Comment: Bingo. I think that worked! Thanks! mind explaining real quick what the AS does? Because obviously it didn't create a new column in my table since it's not an INSERT.. So I'm guessing it makes a "fake" column for that statement?

Comment: It assigns the column to an alias to use for the purpose of that query. :)  You can assign any selected column to an alias using `AS`.  Without it you would have to use the variable/key `$average["CAST(AVG(golfer_handicap) AS DECIMAL (3,1))"]` or something along those lines.  This makes it simpler.

Answer (score -1):

**Solution:** Thanks to @Dawson_Irvine, please see how they solved my problem here rather than read through the comments. Enjoy!

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT golfer_name, golfer_handicap, golfer_ghin FROM golfers WHERE trip_name_table_ID = '$userid'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

$sql2 = "SELECT CAST(AVG(golfer_handicap) AS DECIMAL (3,1)) AS handicap FROM golfers WHERE trip_name_table_ID = '$userid'";
$result2 = $mysqli->query($sql2);
$total = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
```

In the `$sql2` query I have made the query return the average as `‘handicap’` key in the array. Try `$average[‘handicap’]` or change `AS handicap` to `AS golfer_handicap`

New `echo` that worked:

```
echo "<td colspan = '2'> Average Handicap: " ."<b>". $average['handicap'] ."</b></td>";
```